# Why is uniform convergence needed in this proof of Leibniz Integral Rule?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, proof-explanation, fubini-tonelli-theorems

Wikipedia's proof of Leibiz Integral Theorem begins as follows:

> We use Fubini's theorem to change the order of integration. For every $x$ and $h$, such that $h > 0$ and both $x$ and $x+h$ are within $[x_0,x_1]$, we have:
> $$\int_x^{x+h}\int_a^bf_x(x,t)\text{d}t\text{d}x = \int_a^b\int_x^{x+h}f_x(x,t)\text{d}x\text{d}t = \int_a^b\left(f(x+h,t)-f(x,t)\right)\text{d}t = \int_a^bf(x+h,t)\text{d}t-\int_a^bf(x,t)\text{d}t$$
> Note that the integrals at hand are well defined since $f_{x}(x,t)$ is continuous at the closed rectangle $[x_{0},x_{1}]\times [a,b$ and thus also uniformly continuous there; thus its integrals by either $\text{d}t$ or $\text{d}x$ are continuous in the other variable and also integrable by it (essentially this is because for uniformly continuous functions, one may pass the limit through the integration sign, as elaborated below).

***Why is uniform continuity needed here?*** As I recall correctly, we may apply Fubini's theorem is the function under integration (in this case $f_x$) is continuous.

Comment: Uniform continuity is implied by the continuity of $f_x$ on the rectangle $[x_0,x_1] \times [a,b]$ because the rectangle is closed and bounded and hence compact (and continuity on a compact domain implies uniform continuity by the Heine-Cantor theorem).

Comment: @nonducorduco yes, that I understand. But (I think) there would be no point in mentioning it unless it was necessary for the result to hold